# How to stop main when JFrame is closed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I display two `JFrame` objects at the end of my program. But when I close `JFrame`s, `main()` thread does not stop. It waits for me to click on **stop** button (the red rectangle in the picture). But I want main to stop when I close all the `JFrame`s. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: See also this [demo. of `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556).  But really, see my first comment.

Comment: Staggered I can't find a duplicate for this one...

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've read the post you commented. The post refers to two main drawbacks. I have none of them. I am not developing a GUI. So, design is not my main concern.

Comment: @Duncan  No problem, I could.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am just displaying the results of my code. I will take the screenshots and put them in my research paper. Actually, what I am doing is none of your concern.

Comment: *"I will take the screenshots.."*  Speaking of which:  See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am writing the contents of `JFrame` to a `.png` file. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a [window closing listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html):

Be careful about cleaning up after yourself.  You could just call `System.exit()`, but perhaps a better solution would do resource cleanup.

The stop button and window listener could call the same method to ensure consistency.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the default close operation when you initialize your frame using this command:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

According to the Javadocs, this will 'Exit the application using the System exit method' when you close the frame. I just tried this, and if you have two JFrames open, closing one will close all frames and stop the main() thread.

Comment: So, I need to write this the very first `JFrame`. Because I don't want `main()` to stop when I close just one of them/

Comment: ..did you actually try using the code linked in my 2nd comment?  Changing `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` might have answered that question for you within 60 seconds.

Comment: The point you seem to be missing here is that there are multiple `JFrame` objects on screen.  `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is the last thing that needs, since closing one frame will close them all.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood the question. I thought he just wanted everything to close when one frame closed.